# TypeError: Cannot read property 'card' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, drawer

Can anyone please help me how to solve this problem

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'card' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in DrawerViewBase (created by DrawerView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by DrawerView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by DrawerView)
    in DrawerView (created by DrawerNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by DrawerNavigator)
    in DrawerNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App
```

I think `<Drawer.Navigator>` creating this issue.

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.15",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.2",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.6",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
```

Please help me to fix this problem in Drawer navigation

Comment: somewhere in your code you must be doing `card.key`. Which is causing the issue because their is no `card`. You can try to fix it by `card?.key`